# is there any solution for this authentification (login)?

Tags: php, sql

I have this error only when i enter a **wrong email that doesn't exist in database**:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object in
> C:\path\UsersCOntroller.php on line 10

But it works whenever **the password is wrong and the email exists in database!**
Controller:

```
<?php 
class UsersController{
    public function auth(){
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
         
          
            $data["email"] = $_POST["email"];
            $result = User::login($data);
            
            if($_POST["email"]===$result->email  && password_verify($_POST["password"],$result->password)){
                $_SESSION["logged"] = true;
                $_SESSION["email"] = $result->email;
                $_SESSION["fullname"] = $result->fullname;
                $_SESSION["admin"] = $result->admin;
                Redirect::to("home");
            }
            else{
                
                Session::set("error","Wrong email or password");
                Redirect::to("sign");
            }
        }

            
        }
       
    }

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php 
class User{
    static public function login($data){
        $email = $data["email"];
        try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email";
        $stmt = DB::connect()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$email));
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $user;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo "error : ".$ex.getMessage();
    }
    }
 
}

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the e-mail doesn't exist on the database, then `login()` won't return a row.

Comment: Please try to choose a suitable title for your question and your question is vague. Why successfully login with a wrong password? If there is no field called `Email` you will get this error: `Trying to get property 'email' of non-object `. If you enter the wrong email or wrong  password, nothing will happen (you will not be logged in). Here you have to manage the error messages yourself.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and examine the content of `$result`? Of course there's no any issue with wrong password because your database doesn't know if it is wrong or not, but it cannot return  non-existing row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if($result && $_POST["e...
```

to exclude when result is Null